# Visual studio Portable login

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, authentication

I'm working on a website in visual studio for my senior project.  I am trying to set up a login page for the website but since I have to be able to submit the finished project I was wondering if there was a way to set up the website administration tool to work anywhere.

i.e Is it possible to save/set up the sql server database that is used to login to the website on a flash drive where the entire project is stored?  This way even if I open up the project on a different computer I will still be able to access all aspects of the project.

Any links to resources that I can scour would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Visual studio 2012 with asp.net 4.5

Comment: look into sql server's `LocalDb`  It is a local instance of a database, similar to SQLite.  It would be portable with your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want a common database location which should be accessed by all, then you'd need   to make certain that other machines have access to your local machine's database server

1. If you want the entire code plus the database to be present separately on each machine, then you'd need to share a database backup along with the application code folder and each machine would require the database backup to be restored on their database server along with setting up the application.

3.i can also prefer the [Join me](https://join.me/?wt.srch=1&utpk=join%20me&originid=345969&mcomb=soEWpvUxG%7C39179436666%7Cjoin%20me%7Ce%7Ci8rbbhb5l0%7Cc) or [VNC](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/index.aspx?pid=google.r.oc.s.desk.vnc&gclid=CPjUmuzkob0CFWZS4godFmEANQ) or any virtual tools to access your machine

Comment: Yea, I had a feeling that this would be the case.  I feel that both of these options are too tedious to deal with every single day.  I might just use something like join me or vnc to connect to my machine and then work from there if necessary.  Thanks a lot! :D